apt-get update not finishing on debian bookworm container
I'm faced with an issue where building a debian:bookworm container image with an apt-get update instruction on a debian buster machine, completely hangs up without any response.
The Dockerfile in question
FROM debian:bookworm

RUN apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=true -o Debug::Acquire::https=true -o Debug::Acquire::ftp=true -o Debug::Acquire::gpgv=true -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true -o Debug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 && \
    apt-get install -y --force-yes apt-transport-https wget gnupg2 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

Additional debug flags to apt-get have been added for debugging purposes only.
The build stage is stuck at below, which doesn't seem to make sense for me. It has been this way for more than 10 minutes now.
 => [2/2] RUN apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=true -o Debug::Acquire::https=true -o Debug::Acquire::ftp=true -o Debug::Acquire::gpgv=true -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true -o Debug::pkgAcquire::Wor  683.0s
 => => #   Signed-By: 05AB90340C0C5E797F44A8C8254CF3B5AEC0A8F0, AC530D520F2F3269F5E98313A48449044AAD5C5D, B0CAB9266E8C3929798B3EEEBDE6D2B9216EC7A8!, ED541312A33F1128F10B1C6C54404762BBB6E853!
 => => #   NODATA: no
 => => # apt-key succeeded
 => => #  <- gpgv:201%20URI%20Done%0aGPGVOutput:%20GOODSIG%2054404762BBB6E853%0a%20GOODSIG%20BDE6D2B9216EC7A8%0aSigned-By:%2005AB90340C0C5E797F44A8C8254CF3B5AEC0A8F0%0a%20AC530D520F2F3269F5E98313A48449044AAD5C5D%
 => => # 0a%20B0CAB9266E8C3929798B3EEEBDE6D2B9216EC7A8!%0a%20ED541312A33F1128F10B1C6C54404762BBB6E853!%0aFilename:%20/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bookworm-security_InRelease%0aU
 => => # RI:%20gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian-security_dists_bookworm-security_InRelease

The issue is happening only during 1/10 trials, in other cases, I see the gpg verification proceeding to other sources as well
#5 0.354  -> gpgv:600%20URI%20Acquire%0aURI:%20gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bookworm-updates_InRelease%0aFilename:%20/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bookworm-updates_InRelease%0aTarget-Type:%20index%0aTarget-Release:%20bookworm-updates%0aTarget-Repo-URI:%20http://deb.debian.org/debian/%0aTarget-Base-URI:%20http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm-updates/%0aTarget-Site:%20http://deb.debian.org/debian%0aIndex-File:%20true%0aMaximum-Size:%2010000000%0aFail-Ignore:%20true%0aSigned-By:%20/usr/share/keyrings/debian-archive-keyring.gpg%0a%0a
#5 0.357  -> http:600%20URI%20Acquire%0aURI:%20http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/2988d7a0ed222cc0f7f292c3b5925d548703f1211b98740922611330b8782b91%0aFilename:%20/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_bookworm_main_binary-amd64_Packages.xz%0aExpected-Checksum-FileSize:%208786100%0aExpected-SHA256:%202988d7a0ed222cc0f7f292c3b5925d548703f1211b98740922611330b8782b91%0aExpected-MD5Sum:%20fd26f978f97bc3687cb6018d00986b64%0aTarget-Type:%20index%0aTarget-Architecture:%20amd64%0aTarget-Release:%20bookworm%0aTarget-Component:%20main%0aTarget-Repo-URI:%20http://deb.debian.org/debian/%0aTarget-Base-URI:%20http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/%0aTarget-Site:%20http://deb.debian.org/debian%0aIndex-File:%20true%0a%0a

I know I can probably configure timeouts for the update part, but would like to know what is the reason for this hangup and how to recover from it.
Host-machine details:
# uname -r
6.2.0-1018-aws
# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
# cat /etc/debian_version
10.3

